# error telling not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, return

Iwrote a c# code and it seemed correct for me

```
public static BCSMappedTable GetMappedTable(string p_ListName)
    {
        List<BCSDataBase> ConnexionList = BCSManagement.GetAllDataBases();
        bool found = false;
        foreach (BCSDataBase connexion in ConnexionList)
        {
            foreach (BCSMappedTable tabList in connexion.GetMappedTables())
            {
                if (tabList.getListeName().Equals(p_ListName))
                {
                    found = true;
                    return tabList;
                }
            }
        }
        if (found)
            return new BCSMappedTable();
    }
```

but this error keeps appearing

```
error : not all code paths return a value
```

and I don't have a clue why ! I lean I always return the required value

Comment: What they said. Did you mean `if (!found)` near the end? Because whenever `found` is true, you already return earlier in the routine, so `if (found)` at the end again is superfluous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the function, if `found` is false, you don't have a return path...

As you have a `return` statement inside your loop, the function will exit as soon as the item is found, thus you don't need the `found` variable. You can go with something like:

```
public static BCSMappedTable GetMappedTable(string p_ListName)
{
    List<BCSDataBase> ConnexionList = BCSManagement.GetAllDataBases();
    foreach (BCSDataBase connexion in ConnexionList)
    {
        foreach (BCSMappedTable tabList in connexion.GetMappedTables())
        {
            if (tabList.getListeName().Equals(p_ListName))
            {
                // return as soon as the item is found
                return tabList;
            }
        }
    }

    // this code won't be executed if the item was found before...
    return new BCSMappedTable();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because at the end you have

```
if (found) 
            return new BCSMappedTable();
```

what if it wasnt found?

Thing is, it wouldnt get there because when found was set to true, you returned from the function - so, also, all this needs to say is

```
return new BCSMappedTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static BCSMappedTable GetMappedTable(string p_ListName)
    {
        List<BCSDataBase> ConnexionList = BCSManagement.GetAllDataBases();
        bool found = false;
        foreach (BCSDataBase connexion in ConnexionList)
        {
            foreach (BCSMappedTable tabList in connexion.GetMappedTables())
            {
                if (tabList.getListeName().Equals(p_ListName))
                {
                    found = true;
                    return tabList;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!found)
            return new BCSMappedTable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement else part of

```
if (found)
            return new BCSMappedTable();
else 
return tablist1;//or something else
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have:

```
found = true;
return tabList;
```

There is no point setting a value to a local variable and then returning directly after it, as this variable will not be used. `return` basically exits the method with the value you are returning (which should match the type of your method).

As the error states, not all paths return a value. If `found==false` there will be no return value.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
public static BCSMappedTable GetMappedTable(string p_ListName)
{
    List<BCSDataBase> ConnexionList = BCSManagement.GetAllDataBases();
    bool found = false;
    foreach (BCSDataBase connexion in ConnexionList)
    {
        foreach (BCSMappedTable tabList in connexion.GetMappedTables())
        {
            if (tabList.getListeName().Equals(p_ListName))
            {
                found = true;
                return tabList;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found)
      {
        return new BCSMappedTable();
       }
     return found;
}
```

Comment: `found` is a bool... you can't return that.

Comment: Found is a bool, not a BCSMappedTable.